# Is it possible to zip folders together in c#?

Tags: c#, zip, fileinfo, c#-ziparchive

For example, if I have a folder named 2016, and inside that folder are folders Jan-Dec and other files, is there a way to zip those folders together into 2016.zip? Anything I have tried zips together ALL files in the folder, but I am wanting to zip together JUST the folders and no other files within the folder.

Basically, it would be 2016.zip with Jan-Dec folders in the 2016.zip with each of the folders having their respective files in them, not empty folders in the zip.

The following code grabs FILES starting with 00, but not folders.

```
// Where the files are located
string strStartPath = txtTargetFolder.Text;

// Where the zip file will be placed
string strZipPath = @"C:\Users\smelmo\Desktop\testFinish\" + strFileNameRoot + "_" + txtDateRange1.Text.Replace(@"/", "_") + "_" + txtDateRange2.Text.Replace(@"/", "_") + ".zip";

if(File.Exists(strZipPath))
{
    File.Delete(strZipPath);
}

using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(strZipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(strStartPath).GetFiles())
    {
                if (file.Name.StartsWith("00"))
                {
                    var entry = archive.CreateEntryFromFile(Path.Combine(file.Directory.ToString(), file.Name), file.Name);
                }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `typeof()` but it does not grab the folders, or anything.

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(strZipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(strStartPath).GetFiles())
        {
                Type t = file.GetType();
                if (t.Equals(typeof(Directory)))
                {
                    var entry = archive.CreateEntryFromFile(Path.Combine(file.Directory.ToString(), file.Name), file.Name);
                }            
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a zip of empty folders, right?

Comment: @CodyG.No, the Jan-Dec folders would have files in them. I would want to zip the Jan-Dec folders together. So opening 2016.zip would have Jan-Dec folders and then those folders having their respective files.

Comment: Why don't you try `DirectoryInfo(strStartPath).GetDirectories` ? `.GetFiles()` will not return directories...

Comment: I would create the file structure on the drive and then use: ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(strStartPath, strZipPath);  Which would include the folders for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following folder structure:

[image]

This code (updated):

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceFolder = @"c:\temp";
        string zipFilePath = Path.Combine(sourceFolder, "test.zip");

        // TODO: Check if the archive exists maybe?

        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (var directoryName in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder))
            {
                foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName))
                {
                    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                    var entry = archive.CreateEntry($"{dirInfo.Name}\\{fileName}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

produces this zip:

[image]

Comment: But if I wanted the zip to be the folders instead of the .txt files, would I just take out the last `foreach` and create the entry for each directoryName?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. Do you only need a zip with empty folders Jan-Dec?

Comment: I also tried using the exact code (modifying the sourceFolder) and the zip is empty.

Comment: No I need the zip to contain the folders Jan-Dec with each folder having their respective files in them.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code, and also tested it. It produces a zip with relative paths now. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. So relative paths will include the files in them? I am just trying to figure out/learn from what was throwing me off. Thank you for all your help!